# How shap values behave in terms of multicollinearity in Trees, Ensemble, GradientBoosting and GAM/Boosting

Tags: boosting, multicollinearity, generalized-additive-model, ensemble-learning, shapley-value

I set up an experiment with these 8 Regressor Methods:

**sklearn package**

- DecisionTreeRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor

**other packages**

- CatBoostRegressor , ExplainableBoostingRegressor , LGBMRegressor, XGBRegressor

Every method ran with:

- **2000 random_seeds** and
- **3 collinear features**, where feature 2 and 3 are copies of the first one.

I measured a method's management of **multicollinearity** by **shapley_values**  (except for the EBM since its feature importance is already comparable to shapley values)

In general, I **discovered** that dealing with multicollinearity depends on the methods implementation. By default not every Gradient Boosting Technique deals with it the same way. So my original [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116969/is-multicollinearity-a-problem-with-gradient-boosted-trees-i-e-gbm/543590#543590) on a similar topic *was wrong*.

Here is an **Example Output** with random seeds and a shapley_contribution for all three features.
[image]

Now, after the experiment I feel unsatisfied with the results. So I want to improve the experiment:

- Do you have other metrices or extensions in mind to see how the methods deal with multicollinearity compared to each other? e.g. plotting also the constant?
- Do you know of a plot which could combine 8 example plots in one? So that people do not have to look at 8 graphics but instead at only one graphic?

If you want to dive deeper into this experiment, I listed every output plot, the notebook and the data here:
***Experiment files:*** ***https://github.com/OldPatrick/crossvalidated***

Comment: Can you please edit this and make it more concise? 800+ words, with graphs and multiple questions is probably a sign that this needs more focus...

Comment: Ok I will do so tomorrow

Comment: Ok, I reworked the whole question and focused on the things I'm interested in the most.